# Which tag shall be used for questions concerning plattdeutsch

Tags: discussion, tags

Welchen Tag sollen wir verwenden, um Fragen zu verschlagworten, die sich mit plattdeutsch beschäftigen?

Wir haben gegenwärtig [7 Fragen, die mit dem Tag "northern-german" verschlagwortet sind](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/northern-german). Ist es sinnvoll, diesen Tag auch an die plattdeutsch-Threads zu vergeben, oder wäre da linguistisch eine Differenzierung angebracht - mit einem eigenen Tag "plattdeutsch" oder "low-german"?

---

Which tag shall be used for questions concerning plattdeutsch (low-german)?

Currently we have [7 questions tagged "northern-german"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/northern-german). Shall we use this tag for questions dealiing with plattdetusch (low german), too? Or would a tag "plattdeutsch" (or "low-german") be more appropriate from a linguistic point of view?

Comment: btw, welches [tag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tag_Strukturelement_Markierung) ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah, interessant, wusste nicht, dass der Duden hier Neutrum verlangt. Bei solchen Anglizismen ist ja am Anfang immer ein bisschen Bewegung drin, ich warte lieber, bis der Duden das (von mir bisher nur so gehörte) Maskulinum übernimmt, statt mich dem Duden anzupassen :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a low-german tag, and that should be used for questions regarding Plattdeutsch. Indeed some of the northern-german questions should be retagged, we should then reëvaluate the northern-german tag and add a warning that low-german may be more appropriate.

As for the distinction, I think that a question regarding the pronunciation of "st" in Hamburg should have a northern-german tag.

Comment: Oh, we should definitely add 'plattdeutsch' and ''niederdeutsch' as synonyms to the 'low-german' tag then, I guess.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: erledigt.